# SQL: cascade UNION and JOIN

Tags: sql, join, union

I have a union opertaion between two tables

```
SELECT ID_1,
       name_1,
       surname_1,
  FROM T_ONE
 UNION
SELECT ID_2,
       name_2,
       surname_2
  FROM TABLE_2
```

I want to join the result of this `UNION` operation with another table or even with all `TABLE_1`.

How can I handle this new table result of the `UNION`.

for example after the previous `UNION`:

```
RIGHT JOIN TABLE_3
        ON TABLE_3.ID_3 = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.ID_2
```

I really do not know what I need to put instead of the XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX to andle the new table generated by the `UNION`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a derived table like "foo" here, and then JOIN again however you wish:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLE_3
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT ID_1, name_1, surname_1, FROM T_ONE
    UNION --ALL would be more efficient if results do not overlap, as van's comment said
    SELECT ID_2, name_2, surname_2 FROM TABLE_2
    ) foo  ON TABLE_3.ID_3 = foo.ID_1
```

PS. Use LEFT joins: less confusing then RIGHT joins.

Comment: and I would use UNION ALL instead of just UNION in order to avoid sorting the results, since you know they are different (data from tables T_ONE and TABLE_2 do not overlap, do they?)

Comment: Im facing a similar problem, except the unions are on top, and I cannot use right join because its not currently supported on the platform. Is it possible to restructure it to use a left join with unions on the first select?

Comment: Note that joing on union may introduce suboptimal full scans in query execution plan

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a join in both SELECT :

```
SELECT ID_1, name_1, surname_1, FROM T_ONE
RIGHT JOIN TABLE_3 ON TABLE_3.ID_3 = T_ONE.ID_1

UNION

SELECT ID_2, name_2, surname_2 FROM TABLE_2
RIGHT JOIN TABLE_3 ON TABLE_3.ID_3 = TABLE_2.ID_2
```

Or something like that. Don't forget that a UNION eliminates the duplicates, so if you want duplicates to be included, uyse UNION ALL

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID_1, name_1, surname_1, FROM T_ONE

from
(SELECT ID_1, name_1, surname_1, FROM T_ONE
UNION 
SELECT ID_2, name_2, surname_2 FROM TABLE_2 ) foo

left join TABLE_3 

ON TABLE_3.ID_3 =foo.ID_2
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on gbn's answer above for those who have asked.  Here is how to do it with the union as the first part of the left join.

```
SELECT table3.phone, foo.fname, foo.lname, foo.email
FROM
(SELECT table1.fname,table1.lname,table1.email
    FROM table1
UNION
SELECT table2.fname,table2.lname,table2.email
    FROM table2
) foo
LEFT JOIN table3
ON foo.lname = table3.lname
```