# How to compare tables with many unions and join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I'm trying to find rows which are present only in one table. Big table name (consists all rows) is `kwf_uploads`, small tables present in many names. My goal is find rows which exists in `kwf_uploads`, but not exists in other (this example are primary and foreigh keys in tables without relations).

What I did in sql:

```
select id from
kwf_uploads
left join

(SELECT picture_id as id
FROM documents where picture_id is not null
UNION 
SELECT file_id as id
FROM books where file_id is not null
UNION 
SELECT picture_id as id
FROM employee where picture_id is not null
UNION 
SELECT file_id as id
FROM flightFiles where file_id is not null
UNION 
SELECT picture_id as id
FROM tasks where picture_id is not null
UNION 
SELECT picture_id as id
FROM trainingContentQuestions where picture_id is not null
UNION 
SELECT picture_id as id
FROM trainingQuestions where picture_id is not null) foo  

ON kwf_uploads.id = foo.id
```

Find it on: [SQL: cascade UNION and JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418431/sql-cascade-union-and-join)

But it fails with error: `SQL (1052): Column "id" in field list is ambiguous`.

I don't want to use join with every table, because I'm not good in joins and sql becomes very large and unreadable. I also tried `not exists` contrustion without any results.
I think we can find a better solution =)

Result from `select id from kwf_uploads` query (9690 rows):

[image]

Result from union queries (6096 rows):

[image]

In result I want to see 3594 (9690 minus 6096) rows.

Comment: Your question isnt clear. Show us some data and expect result. BTW just because you arent good in something doesnt mean you cant learn. `join` are the best tool.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Done.

Comment: so `upload` = `union( documents, books, employee, flightFiles, tasks, trainingContentQuestions, trainingQuestions)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UNION (when used by itself, without ALL) is an "expensive" operation.

There is an alternative, NOT EXISTS. This construct is a "semi join" and I suspect may be less expensive than a union approach.

```
SELECT
      id
FROM kwf_uploads AS u
WHERE NOT EXISTS     (SELECT NULL FROM documents WHERE u.id = picture_id )
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM books WHERE u.id = file_id )
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM employee WHERE u.id = picture_id )
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM flightFiles WHERE u.id = file_id )
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM tasks WHERE u.id = picture_id )
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM trainingContentQuestions WHERE u.id = picture_id )
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM trainingQuestions WHERE u.id = picture_id )
```

Comment: Maybe the `union` is expensive but doing  7 exists for each row looks expensive too.

Comment: not nearly as expensive as a union. EXISTS / NOT EXISTS is surprisingly efficient as all it behaves like a join but does not have to "pull" any data into the resultset. By the way; never assume that briefer SQL code is equal to more efficient operation of that code. Quite often the reverse is true.

Comment: You right! Checked on my localhost after rebooting mysql process. With `UNION` 1,482 sec. (+ 1,607 sec. network) and with `NOT EXISTS` 0,109 sec. (+ 0,109 sec. network).

Comment: You should also try the previous query but using `UNION ALL` instead. This might be faster. Will be faster than `UNION` by itself.

Comment: Just checked `UNION ALL`...OMG...27,488 sec. (+ 31,356 sec. network)

Comment: wow! sorry that was unexpected. well `NOT EXISTS` is the fastest

Comment: @Used_By_Already Close your bracket at line 5, I can't edit because need 6 symbols =)

Comment: @Used_By_Already Despite the different type of query (not as I asked at start), the answer seems most appropriate to me. I will use it for my script. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**To fix your current error**

Prefix Id column with proper resultset alias. In this case `kwf_uploads.id`. Because Id exists in both resultsets.

**To get desired output**

Add `Where foo.id is null`. This will fetch those ids which failed in join, those are the ids you want.

```
  select kwf_uploads.id from
        kwf_uploads
        left join

        (SELECT picture_id as id
        FROM documents where picture_id is not null
        UNION 
        SELECT file_id as id
        FROM books where file_id is not null
        UNION 
        SELECT picture_id as id
        FROM employee where picture_id is not null
        UNION 
        SELECT file_id as id
        FROM flightFiles where file_id is not null
        UNION 
        SELECT picture_id as id
        FROM tasks where picture_id is not null
        UNION 
        SELECT picture_id as id
        FROM trainingContentQuestions where picture_id is not null
        UNION 
        SELECT picture_id as id
        FROM trainingQuestions where picture_id is not null) foo  

        ON kwf_uploads.id = foo.id
        where foo.id is null
```

Comment: A comment would be nice.

Comment: I miss table name... thx! I can't understand why using `foo.id is null` we get desired result? I see `is not null` in every union select before.

Comment: @Sogl : you are doing a left join between table and union result set with this condition `ON kwf_uploads.id = foo.id`. Left join will fetch all the results from left table even if there are not matches on right table. So, in the final result set, if you see foo.id as null, that means they exist in first table but not second. Try removing `where foo.id is null' and see the results. You will understand.

Answer (score 1):

Beside DarkKnight answer:

You dont need include `where` on each `union select`. Worst case you get one `NULL` from all the `UNION` but that wont appear on the `LEFT JOIN` anyway

```
select kwf_uploads.id 
from kwf_uploads
left join
    (
    SELECT picture_id as id FROM documents
    UNION 
    SELECT file_id as id FROM books
    UNION 
    SELECT picture_id as id FROM employee
    UNION 
    SELECT file_id as id FROM flightFiles
    UNION 
    SELECT picture_id as id FROM tasks
    UNION 
    SELECT picture_id as id FROM trainingContentQuestions 
    UNION 
    SELECT picture_id as id FROM trainingQuestions
    ) foo      
ON kwf_uploads.id = foo.id
where foo.id is null
```

Comment: Thank you, it works that it should! But I can't understand why it works with `foo.id is null` and not works without. =) Union selects shows me 1 NULL

Comment: Because even when `union` have a `null`, left side of the join doesn't have any `null`. So no match is made.

Comment: If you insist on using a unioned approach for this query you can save expense and get the same result by using `UNION ALL`. It does not matter in this query if an upload ID is used in more than one table because you are looking for those that have no references at all. So, do yourself a favour, use `UNION ALL` instead.